# Select only one out of two input streams

Tags: tensorflow

I am having a graph which should choose between using either of two input streams at each session call. If a flag is set, stream_1 should be used, if it is not set, stream_2 should be used. `tf.cond` can accomplish this, but as the documentation says, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond, the inputs are computed regardless of whether or not they are actually used. As stream_1 is computationally heavy I would rather not use such a solution. Is there another way of accomplishing the same thing, where stream_1 is not computed at all when the flag is not set?